# Why can't I pipe the output of uuencode to mailx in a single Perl open statement?

Tags: perl, unix, attachment, hp-ux, mailx

Here's my code that is not working:

```
print "To: ";  my $to=<>;  chomp $to;
print "From: ";  my $from=<>;  chomp $from;
print "Attach: "; my $attach=<>; chomp $attach;
print "Subject: "; my $subject=<>; chomp $subject;
print "Message: "; my $message=<>; chomp $message;

my $mail_fh = \*MAIL;
open $mail_fh, "uuencode $attach $attach |mailx -m -s \"$subject\" -r $from $to";
print $mail_fh $message;
close($mail_fh);
```

The mailx command works fine off the command line, but not in this Perl script context.

Any idea what I'm missing?

---

I suspect that this line's format/syntax:

```
open $mail_fh, "uuencode $attach $attach |mailx -m -s \"$subject\" -r $from $to";
```

is the culprit.

Comment: fyi - the entire script works when uuencode $attach $attach is removed from the line beginning with "open"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an extra `|` at the beginning:

```
open $mail_fh, "|uuencode $attach $attach |mailx -m -s \"$subject\" -r $from $to";
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use external binaries for either the uuencode or the mailx bit? UUencode is almost trivial with [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

Comment: Quite trivial - `my $encoded = pack 'u', $data;` The `u` template is a bit weird, and isn't explained well in perlfunc.  There is an example in perlpacktut though: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Uuencoding

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to send mail. See the [How do I send mail?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-send-mail%3f) in [perlfaq9](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html).